# Telegram api получить сообщения с канала

Tags: api, telegram-bot, telegram

**Ситуация такая:** есть общий чат с количеством участников 5к. За один час там добавляется около 300 сообщений. **Вопрос:** есть ли какой-нибудь способ получить сообщения (через API или любым другим способом), чтоб в дальнейшем отфильтровать только сообщения 2-3 человек.

Я пробовал получать сообщения так:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<bot_key>/getUpdates?chat_id=@<channel_name>
```

но в ответ всегда приходит:

```
{"ok":true,"result":[]}
```

Насколько я понял, Телеграмм в этом плане сильно ограничил ботов, но может есть какой-то способ?

Comment: бот является администратором этой группы?

Comment: @Anatol к сожалению, нет. Как получать сообщения боту-администратору я находил решения.

Comment: `privacy mode` выключен?

Comment: @Anatol    да выключен, но результат выполнения этой команды не изменяется в зависимости от режима.

Comment: я бы не стал так утверждать, возможно просто после включения/выключения режима новых сообщений не публиковалось

Comment: @Anatol   так в том то и проблема что там в час 300+ сообщений. Поэтому и хочется отфильтровать пару человек, мнение которых мне важно от 90% всякого спама и бреда.

Comment: @Anatol   Спасибо за помощь, проблема решена. Нужно было просто добавить бота в этот  чат)) И тогда можно просто писать getUpdates

Comment: *Нужно было просто добавить бота в этот чат* - рукалицо

Comment: можно без бота сообщения собирать из под обычного пользователя. К примеру, есть telegram cli который простой api на сокетах + json предоставляет.

Comment: https://github.com/pyrogram/pyrogram/blob/develop/examples/get_history.py

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Исходя из количества просмотров вопрос интересен, поэтому дам развернутый ответ на свой же вопрос. Во первых чтобы получить сообщения из группы нужно добавить бота в группу/канал. После чего достаточно выполнить команду:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<bot_key>/getUpdates
```

И вы получите все **новые** сообщения со всех групп в которых этот бот есть. Если в результате вы получили:

```
{"ok":true,"result":[]}
```

Это означает, что команда выполнена успешно, но новых сообщений нет. Чтобы получать новые сообщения конкретной группы нужно вписать id группы. Как вариант его можно получить написав сообщение в той группе id которой нужно получить и выполнить команду указанную в самом начале. В ответ вы получите:

```
{"ok":true,"result":[{"update_id":156401956,
"message":{"message_id":5423,"from":{"id":53454165,"is_bot":false,"first_name":" 
<Your Name>","username":"<Your UserName>"},"chat":{"id":-100134567153,
"title":"<Group Title>","type":"supergroup"},"date":1547190599,"text":"test"}}]}
```

Соответственно нужно выполнить команду

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<bot_key>/getUpdates?chat_id=-100134567153
```

Так же вы можете отправлять сообщения в эту группу с помощью бота:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<bot_key>/sendMessage?chat_id=-100134567153&text=test%20test
```

Comment: Спасибо, а админом его нужно делать?

Comment: `Во первых чтобы получить сообщения из группы нужно добавить бота в группу/канал.`
Как это сделать для канала (я не администратор).

Comment: @IvanPruchai Если группа открыта то через кнопку Add members. Еще вроде как-то можно просто через упоминания бота в чате (через @botName), но во втором способе я не уверен. Если добавлять пользователей могут только админы и вы не один из них, то никак.

Comment: @VadimPavlovich я так понимаю, что в групу добавить можно, а в канал нельзя?

Comment: @IvanPruchai  К чужому нельзя. К своему можно через ControllerBot.

Comment: @VadimPavlovich спасибо. В общем пришлось использовать API телеграма на прямую, создавая свое приложение и уже там можно делать почти что хочешь :)

Comment: чо это зажесть вообще,кто это лайкает, идем в телеграм BOT API и смотрит что такое getupdates https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates , это вообще обновление самой системы,и там ни как не передать chat_id=-100134567153, и уж точно он не выдаст новые сообщения. Ниже urmurmur указал как верно парсить каналы, и там без разницы чужик или свои, и ни какого бота не нужно встраивать

Answer (score 0):

Напиши не имя канала, а его ID.
Получить ID можно, например, переслав сообщение боту @ShowJsonBot

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться сервисом [TaaS](https://www.t-a-a-s.ru/) - он позволяет легко создать клиент Телеграма который через Telegram API может получить сообщения из любой группы.

1. Создайте клиент в Таасе используя номер телефона вашего телеграм аккаунта и получите API ключ
2. Используя полученный API ключ, сделайте HTTP запрос к Таас чтобы получить сообщения из группы с помощью метода getChatHistory, вот так:

```
    GET https://api.t-a-a-s.ru
    {
      "api_key": "YOUR_API_KEY", // ваш API ключ
      "@type": "getChatHistory",
      "chat_id": "12345678", // chat_id чата
      "limit": "100",
      "offset": "0",
      "from_message_id": "0"
    }
```